# PowerShell function always returns 0 when SQL returns no record

Tags: sql, powershell

I am experiencing a very strange behaviour in PowerShell. Consider the following PowerShell function:

```
function Select-SQLRecords($connString, $query)
{
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $connString

    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $query
    $SqlCmd.Connection  = $SqlConnection

    $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet

    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)

    $SqlConnection.Close()

    $data = $dataset.Tables[0].Rows

    if($data.Count -eq 0)
    {
        return ""
    }

    return $data
}
```

When I call the function

```
$recordRows = Select-SQLRecords $connectionstring $sqlquery
```

if the query does result in rows being retrieved, then $recordRows will be set for those rows. However, if the query does not result in rows being retrieved, then $recordRows is set to 0, even when I specifically tell the function to return "".

I tried to test by placing return "" at different places in the function and found that the function will return whatever I want it to return if I place the return statement before $SqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet). But as soon as $SqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet) is executed, it will always return 0 if no rows retrieved.

Anyone experienced this before?

Cheers
Conax

Answer (score 2):

After further research, I finally found the reason.

This line

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
```

generates its own output (number of records filled into the dataset).
When this output is not captured, e.g.

```
$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($dataSet)
```

that output gets returned to the function caller as well.

Previously I didn't notice that when there were records returned, it also had a record count added to the function return.